# Why no classic report generator for xbap(WPF)

Tags: wpf, reporting, xbap

I can not find a specific solution for report generation in XBAP or maybe WPF.
has a classic solution? (or best solution)
example:

1. Use Crystal Or Microsoft Report through ASPX pages.
2. convert report pages to portable formatted such as photo and send to XBAP app.
3. or ...

suppose the user is familiar with classic solution.

Comment: or solution for force user to ignore reports on applications?(same as microsoft for xbap)!!!!